# Scheduled automatic FTP website backup solution?

Tags: backup, ftp, automation, scheduled-tasks

I was wondering if there was a way to schedule automatic FTP site backup with any free or open-source software?

Clients like FileZilla do not have an automatic backup (ftp download) option. Is there a way to schedule this with any program, by using the windows task scheduler?

Or maybe we need to use a macro program like imacro in combination with FireFTP to do the job? Do you think using macro is a feasible and secure(reliable) solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like going the batch file way you could try [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=96269) assuming you are on windows of course. Try that out with schedule tasks. But I imagine there is a software solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, you could try using [NetDrive](http://www.freewarereview.info/2007-01/netdrive_-_browse_ftp_file_structures_like_virtual_explorer-style_drives.html) to map an ftp site as a network drive and then use your favorite backup program to schedule a sync. Or, try the free [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm), which will sync directly with FTP servers.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a complete opensource solution that will allow you to do what you're asking.  You could combine multiple services to get the task done. Another option is to setup another machine and use rsync to synchronize the data.

I know you were opposed to non free/open source, but have you considered a web based solution like [SitePlanB](http://www.siteplanb.com) or a windows application like SiteVault (sorry can't link 2 URLs as a newcommer site-vault.com).  Both are very reasonably priced and eliminate a lot of the headache.

Answer (score 1):

With [Website 2 Backup](http://website2backup.com) you can do automated website files and databases backups and send them to FTP (emails, or locally). It manage the split of archives to do not reach server maximum allowed upload size.

Answer (score 1):

[DotSpirit](http://www/dotspirit.com) has released a software based on [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) to backup files from your PC to their 250GB online storage

Answer (score 0):

For something free I think http://limagito.com/ could help, but If you need something online you can check this http://www.autofilemove.com/